# Issue mapping Json string with ko.mapping

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, knockout.js, webmethod

On the server side I have a Asp.Net Web application, a WebMethod returns a Json string serialized just like this one:

```
Object { d= "[{"Id":"1","Name":"COMERCIAL BANK"},
 {"Id":"2","Name":"AZTEC BANK"},
 {"Id":"3","Name":"EL SALVADOR BANK"}]" }
```

When I try mapping that result using `var mappedBanks = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data.d)`, and then use `console.log(mappedBanks)` all I get printed is `c()` and is like that mappedBanks, that should be an array, has no elements because I can iterate on it and when I try to print the first element, the console says `undefined`. Is there a problem with the Json? or I´m not mapping it right.

Comment: JavaScript string can't have double quotes inside double quotes. You need either escape them (`\"`) or use single quotes (`'`) inside/outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ko.mapping.toJSON` requires first argument to be an *object*, not an *array*. Your option is to make your JSON-encoded array to be property value.

```
var mappedBanks = ko.mapping.fromJS({ items: JSON.parse(data.d) });
console.log(mappedBanks.items);
```

Comment: I did what you told me to, but i´m still getting the "c()" when I print "mappedBanks.Items"

Comment: actually it works but I changed it for this  "var mappedBanks = { items: JSON.parse(data.d) };" ..

Comment: Your code is the same excepting that `items` will be plain array, not observableArray.